# Formal verification with yices -- broken pipe

Tags: yosys

I am trying to formally verify my verilog FPGA design `led_walker.v`. So I first synthesize it to an `.smt2` file:

```
┌───┐
│ $ │ ziga > ziga--workstation > 001--led_walker--verification
└─┬─┘ 
  └─> yosys \
    -p "read_verilog -sv -formal led_walker.v" \
    -p "prep -nordff -top led_walker" \
    -p "write_smt2 led_walker.smt2 "
```

I then use synthesized `led_walker.smt2` file with `yosys-smtbmc` to formally verify my design using *BMC method*:

```
┌───┐
│ $ │ ziga > ziga--workstation > 001--led_walker--verification
└─┬─┘ 
  └─> yosys-smtbmc led_walker.smt2
##   0:00:00  Solver: yices
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/yosys-smtbmc", line 392, in <module>
    smt.write(line)
  File "/usr/share/yosys/smtio.py", line 413, in write
    self.p_write(stmt + "\n", True)
  File "/usr/share/yosys/smtio.py", line 297, in p_write
    if flush: self.p.stdin.flush()
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

This command tries to use a solver `yices` and it looks like it is broken...
I am completely new to formal verification and as a newcommer I don't know if this error is due to my flawed design or is this a system problem? To me it looks like a python error...

Here is another try but this time I use `-i` flag that instructs `yices` to formally verify my design using *induction method*. It fails again *(same thing actually)*:

```
┌───┐
│ $ │ ziga > ziga--workstation > 001--led_walker--verification
└─┬─┘ 
  └─> yosys-smtbmc -i led_walker.smt2
##   0:00:00  Solver: yices
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/yosys-smtbmc", line 398, in <module>
    smt.write(line)
  File "/usr/share/yosys/smtio.py", line 430, in write
    self.p_write(stmt + "\n", True)
  File "/usr/share/yosys/smtio.py", line 314, in p_write
    if flush: self.p.stdin.flush()
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Binary `yosys-smtbmc` was installed as part of the official package `yosys` that is currently version:

```
┌───┐
│ $ │ ziga > ziga--workstation > ~
└─┬─┘ /dev/pts/10
  └─> yosys -V
Yosys 0.9 (git sha1 1979e0b)
```

Solver `yices` *(version 2.6.2)* was downloaded as precompiled binaries from official website [here](https://yices.csl.sri.com/), extracted and installed using the `install-yices` script.

They are installed like this and visible to the system:

```
┌───┐
│ $ │ ziga > ziga--workstation > local
└─┬─┘ 
  └─> pwd
/usr/local

┌───┐
│ $ │ ziga > ziga--workstation > local
└─┬─┘ 
  └─> ag -l --search-binary yices
include/yices_exit_codes.h
include/yices_types.h
include/yices_limits.h
include/yices.h
bin/yices-sat
lib/libyices.so.2.6.2
bin/yices-smt
bin/yices-smt2
bin/yices
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening? Is there any possibility that installing older versions of the ˙yices˙ would help? Or maybee I am missing some python packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. Problem is with the precompiled binaries! If I get the latest development sources from the GitHub and then compile, everything works.

This is how to properly do it:

```
git clone https://github.com/SRI-CSL/yices2.git yices2
cd yices2
autoconf
./configure
make -j$(nproc)
sudo make install
```

Too bad that there is no debian *(not ubuntu PPA repository that they provide and is not working)* package!

Comment: I also found out that `yosys-smtbmc` supports other solvers! Among those these three are available as official Debian packages: `z3`, `boolector`, `cvc4`. They are slower than `yices`! Solver *"Mathsat5"* is also supported, but there is no official Debian package...